# Does AWS API GATEWAY CLIENT SDK helps with refreshing cognito access token?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I was looking into the AWS API GATEWAY CLIENT SDK code and didnt find any code which refreshes the cognito access token after an hour automatically.

Am I right ?? -Will I need to check the refresh token functionality manually ?

Comment: It should. Which SDK platform are you using? Have you tested this?

Comment: I am using JS Sdk - generated from aws api gateway console screen

Comment: As long as you are using "AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials", the access key and secret key used with the SDK will be refreshed automatically.

Comment: No I am not using AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials - its an sdk generated from API Gateway console, after API is deployed